# codeigniter connect with postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

The code is connect but the database group is invalid i.e.  the code doesnt connect with the database because the setting in database.php file is invalid.
 where do we look for the error and how to resolve this.

```
You have specified an invalid database connection group (db) in your config/database.php file.
```

This file show error but not specified to where is error

```
config/database.php code below: 


$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=success_story',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'puneetchhabra',
    'password' => 'shambhu',
    'database' => 'success_story',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

The database.php file code is show what seems to be the error.

browser has this error unable to connect.

```
Message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: missing "=" `after "localhost" in connection info string`
```

Be kind and suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your `$active_group` ? in your database.php you should declare `$active_group = 'default'; `

Comment: `$active_group = 'default';` already coded

Comment: i don't think so - because Codeigniter tells you it is `$active_group = 'db';` (according to your error message)

Comment: man its already coded

Comment: i didnt quite get you you mean instead of `'default'` i write `'db'`.
is that what you mean ?

Comment: nope, what i mean is - somewhere in your code you've specified `$active_group = 'db';` - i don't know where - maybe you have a second database file ? take a look @ https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB.php#L101 - this is exact your error message - and CI thinks `$active_group` is `db`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'localhost',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'puneetchhabra',
    'password' => 'shambhu',
    'database' => 'success_story',
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre', # or PDO
    'port' => '' #ex 5433
);
```

make sure

1. You can connect outside the application ([pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/))
2. In php.ini enable extenxtion `php_pdo_pgsql` (for pdo) and `php_pgsql`(for postgre).

Comment: the error still remains i'll update the php.ini and enable extension

Comment: restart the xamp/LAMP

Comment: hello again, so the code for the following extension is enable; conf/php.ini. where does the problem exist ?

Comment: so i narrowed it down to the error is 
`Message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: missing "=" after "localhost" in connection info string`